# Webcam not working under Opencv - How to solve this?

Tags: python, opencv, webcam

Here is my code :

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascase_frontalface_default.xml')
eye_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_eye.xml')

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    ret, img = cap.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray,1.3,5)
    for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(img, (x,y), (x+w, y+h), (255,0,0), 2)
        roi_gray = gray[y:y+h, x:x+w]
        roi_color = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]

        eye = eye_cascade.detectMultiScale(roi_gray)
        for (ex,ey,ew,eh) in eye:
            cv2.rectangle(roi_color, (ex,ey), (ex+ew, ey+eh), (0,255,0), 2 )
    cv2.imshow('img',img)
    k= cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xff 
    if k == 27:``
        break

cap.release()
cap.destroyAllWindows()
```

These are the errors I'm getting:

> error: OpenCV(4.2.0)
>   C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:182:
>   error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function
>   'cv::cvtColor'
>
> error                                     Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>         3 while True:
>         4     ret, img = cap.read()
>   ----> 5     gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
>         6     faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray,1.3,5)
>         7     for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
>
> error: OpenCV(4.2.0)
>   C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:182:
>   error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function
>   'cv::cvtColor'

Answer (score 1):

in your code have 3 little errors:
1=  ```` if k == 27:``` for solve first that delete `` 2= ````cap.destroyAllWindows()`for solve secound, type`cv2.destroyAllWindows() `3=`('haarcascase_frontalface_default.xml')`for solve third ,just type this`haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml`
you type cascase but that is cascade.

Answer (score 0):

There could be numerous reasons as to why it doesn't work (eg. some OS will require that you grant permission to your term to access the webcam), however there's a couple of issues with your code:

- start of the while loop: you don't check the value of the parameter `ret`. It's good practice to check its value with a small check like `if not ret: break` to exit the loop. That won't help with your webcam not working, but that will prevent the error that you are seeing (`ret`is False, so `img` is likely empty and had no data)
- End of your code. `destroyAllWindows` is a method in the `cv2` namespace, not a property of your capture. You should call `cv2.destroyAllWindows()` instead of `cap.destroyAllWindows()`